# Custom osm2po postprocessor to generate a node file and a way file

Tags: osm2po

For a software component were using we need to provide 2 input files. One with a list of nodes (nodeId, lat, lon) and one with ways (fromNodeId, toNodeId, oneway, maxSpeed, lenght).

To create these 2 files I created a custom postprocessor class, you can find the code here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5047904

To get the Nodes I read the "tn_raw.2po" file, for the ways the "sw_all.2po" file. This works great, but now my node output files contains all osm nodes. What I would like, is that the file only contains the nodes used in the ways file.

Is it possible to only output the used nodes in a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **sv_all.2po** and **sw_all.2po** instead.

The corresponding classes are:

- Vertex
- SegmentedWay

Here is a sample of how to loop over the Vertices:

```
File inFile = new File("sv_all.2po");
InStream is = new InStreamDisk(inFile);
byte type = is.readByte(); // We know what's in there

Vertex vertex = new Vertex();
while (!is.isEof()) {
  vertex.readFromStream(is);
  System.out.println(vertex);
}

is.close();
```

Every *.2po-file follows the same loop pattern.
Here is the original code for the **cmd=d** option.

```
public class Debug {

    public static void dump2poFile(Config config) throws Exception {

        InStream inStream = new InStreamDisk(config.getFiles().get(0));
        byte varType = inStream.readByte();
        Var var = VarTypeDesk.create(varType);
        int i = 0;
        while (!inStream.isEof()) {
            System.out.println("[" + (i++) + "] " +  var.readFromStream(inStream));
        }
        inStream.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx! Works great if I use the vertex file